# How to avoid casting while extracting fields from GenericRecord in avro?

Tags: java, casting, type-conversion, avro

I am working with Avro and I am trying to extract few fields from it in a generic way. I have a [GenericRecord](https://avro.apache.org/docs/1.7.6/api/java/org/apache/avro/generic/GenericRecord.html) object from avro and I want to extract few fields from it.

Below are the methods which does everything:

```
  public static Object extract(GenericRecord genericRecord, String fieldName) {
    Object result = new Object();
    for (Field field : genericRecord.getSchema().getFields()) {
      if (field.name().equalsIgnoreCase(fieldName))
        return fromAvro(genericRecord.get(field.name()), field.schema());
    }
    return result;
  }

  private static Object fromAvro(Object obj, Schema schema) {
    if (obj == null)
      return null;
    switch (schema.getType()) {
      case UNION:
        return fromAvroUnion(obj, schema);
      case ARRAY:
        return fromAvroArray(obj, schema);
      case STRING:
        if (obj.equals("null") || obj.toString().equals("null"))
          return null;
        else
          return obj.toString();
      case MAP:
        return fromAvroMap(obj, schema);
      case NULL:
        return obj;
      case BOOLEAN:
        return Boolean.valueOf(obj.toString());
      case DOUBLE:
        return Double.valueOf(obj.toString());
      case FLOAT:
        return Float.valueOf(obj.toString());
      case INT:
        return Integer.valueOf(obj.toString());
      case LONG:
        return Long.valueOf(obj.toString());
    }
  }

  private static Object fromAvroArray(Object obj, Schema schema) {
    List<Object> array = new ArrayList<Object>();
    for (Object element : (GenericData.Array) obj) {
      array.add(fromAvro(element, schema.getElementType()));
    }
    return array;
  }

  private static Object fromAvroMap(Object obj, Schema schema) {
    Map<String, Object> convertedMap = new HashMap<>();
    // CharSequence because the string can be configured as either Utf8 or String.
    for (Entry<CharSequence, Object> e : ((Map<CharSequence, Object>) obj).entrySet()) {
      convertedMap.put(e.getKey().toString(), fromAvro(e.getValue(), schema.getValueType()));
    }
    return convertedMap;
  }

  private static Object fromAvroUnion(Object obj, Schema schema) {
    List<Schema> types = schema.getTypes();
    if (types.size() < 1) {
      throw new AvroRuntimeException("Union has no types");
    }
    if (types.size() == 1) {
      return fromAvro(obj, types.get(0));
    } else if (types.size() > 2) {
      throw new AvroRuntimeException(
          "Unions may only consist of a concrete type and null in cascading.avro");
    } else if (!types.get(0).getType().equals(Type.NULL)
        && !types.get(1).getType().equals(Type.NULL)) {
      throw new AvroRuntimeException(
          "Unions may only consist of a concrete type and null in cascading.avro");
    } else {
      Integer concreteIndex = (types.get(0).getType() == Type.NULL) ? 1 : 0;
      return fromAvro(obj, types.get(concreteIndex));
    }
  }
```

Below is how I am using above `extract` method to extract individual fields from `GenericRecord` object. Right now I am just extracting, `String` `Integer` data type fields but I may need to extract other data type fields as well.

Now my question is. Is there any way I can avoid casting because right now I am casting each data type while extracting fields from it. I think *whenever there is a cast, there must be better way* to do things which can avoid casting.

```
Map<String, String> payload = (Map<String, String>) extract(genericRecord, "payload");
String clientId = (String) extract(genericRecord, "clientId");
Integer deviceId = (Integer) extract(genericRecord, "deviceId");
```

Comment: Why not use `SpecificRecord`?

Answer (score 0):

> Now my question is. Is there any way I can avoid casting because right
>   now I am casting each data type while extracting fields from it. I
>   think whenever there is a cast, there must be better way to do things
>   which can avoid casting.

You use very generic methods because `GenericRecord` from Avro is a very generic map (it uses `Object` as keys and `Object` as values).
In your case, casting is unfortunately unavoidable at a time or at another one since you work with very weak-typed data : `Object` class.
Now, you could make it in the utility class rather than in client-side.
It would make the job less painful but not more secure at runtime.

You could change `extract()` method in this way :

```
   @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
   public static <T> T extract(GenericRecord genericRecord, String fieldName) {
    for (Field field : genericRecord.getSchema().getFields()) {
      if (field.name().equalsIgnoreCase(fieldName))
        return (T) fromAvro(genericRecord.get(field.name()), field.schema());
    }
    return null;
   }
```

And now in the client side you could do :

```
Map<String, String> payload = extract(genericRecord, "payload");
String clientId = extract(genericRecord, "clientId");
Integer deviceId = extract(genericRecord, "deviceId");
```

Comment: It's not working. I tried changing to what you suggested. It is complaining on all the cases of switch statements. One example error for string case is `Type mismatch: cannot convert from String to T`.

Comment: Indeed. You should also cast to `(T)` the return of all methods you invoke and when you return a not null  value in the `switch`. I edited to illustrate. I also added the     `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")` on the method

Comment: Also I do have to change my `extract` method as well? Correct? Because  it gives me an error as of now.

Comment: I updated my answer. Finally, you need only to introduce the `T` generic in the higher level call, that is in the `extract()` method and to cast to `T` the return of  the`fromAvro()` method.  Besides, I think that the `Object result` variable is not required since if no field matches in the schema you should return a `null` value.